# Trajeto entre 2 pontos com polylines, google maps route

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

Fiz um app usando flutter onde quero determinar um trajeto entre dois pontos. Eu até consigo fazer, mas o problema é que a linha que liga os pontos A, B não respeita as ruas...

Eu uso um package, **google_map_polyline** que pede uma chave de acesso (`API_KEY`), mas que sempre que compilo me devolve uma `exception` e por isso acho que preciso de uma conta paga para que a chave possa funcionar.

Alguém sabe o porque dessa exceção ou tem alguma solução de como fazer a linha seguir o trajeto das ruas sem esse package ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`Exception`:

```
I/flutter (21333): error!!!!
E/flutter (21333): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
E/flutter (21333): Receiver: null
E/flutter (21333): Tried calling: iterator
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #1      new List.from  (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:54:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #2      new List.of  (dart:core/list.dart:142:65)[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (21333): #3      Polyline.clone[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (21333): #4      keyByPolylineId.<anonymous closure>[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #5      MappedIterator.moveNext  (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:395:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #6      MapMixin.addEntries  (dart:collection/maps.dart:172:23)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #7      new Map.fromEntries  (dart:core/map.dart:187:17)[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (21333): #8      keyByPolylineId[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (21333): #9      new PolylineUpdates.from[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter (21333): #10     _GoogleMapState._updatePolylines[39;49m
E/flutter (21333): <asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;248mE/flutter (21333): #11     _GoogleMapState.didUpdateWidget[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #12     StatefulElement.update[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #13     Element.updateChild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #14     ComponentElement.performRebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #15     Element.rebuild[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #16     BuildOwner.buildScope[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #17     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #18     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #19     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #20     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #21     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #22     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #23     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #24     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #25     _invoke  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter (21333): #26     _drawFrame  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)[39;49m
E/flutter (21333):
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Eu sei o porque dessa exceção! É porque o *interator* está sendo chamado mas está NULL... Agora, se quiser uma ajuda melhor, coloque partes do seu fonte que mostrem como você está montando esse mapa e a rota.

Comment: Usar a API do Google que desenha certinho a rota, respeitando as ruas como você quer, é preciso investir um pouco de dinheiro pois a mesma é paga.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro, é como suspeitei... Enfim, obrigado pela informação !